# UDP socket programming python 3.5 - Client not receiving servers data

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, udp

I'm having trouble with my socket programs in python. I'm trying to send a byte string to my client program. My server seems to be sending the data, but client isn't receiving it. I won't post all my code as they are lengthy programs, but here is what I'm using to send that data (seems to be working):

```
server.sendto(packed_data, (host, port))
```

And here is from my client program:

```
readable, writeable, error = select.select([server], [], [], 1)

    if readable: # Ensure we can now read from the socket 
        data, addr = server.recvfrom(1024)
        print(data.decode('utf8')) # Convert back to string
```

The server socket is not readable so it just times out.

Comment: Some things to check:  (1) is there a firewall running on your client computer that is blocking incoming UDP packets?  If so, disable it.  (2) If you run Wireshark on the client computer, do you see any UDP packets coming in from the server computer?  If so, check that your client is listening on the same port that the incoming packet is addressed to.  If not, check that your server is sending packets to the correct IP address.

Comment: Server `idle` and client `CMD` , can't handle all in one solution ! @JeremyFriesner comments `on same machine` : need use `server.bind` and client `create_conection`. mean : `Available_port  >> Target_port`. Like this: `**HTTP port isn't 80 for client !**`